# How to print the problematic row in exception

Tags: python, pandas

I'm using Pandas in my code and while manipulating some data frame using the code below:

```
def exit(exitCode, errorMsg=None, monitor_thread=None):
   if exitCode is not None:
       logger.error(errorMsg)
       logger.error(traceback.format_exc())
   sys.exit(exitCode)

try:
    results['name'] = results['name'].astype(float).astype(int)
except Exception as e:  # catch *all* exceptions
    exit("Failed to convert name" + str(e), 8)
```

I get this error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "DIST\FDmanInfo.py", line 206, in
>
> File "DIST\FDmanInfo.py", line 191, in main
>
> File "\local\Python\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line
>   3054, in astype
>       raise_on_error=raise_on_error, **kwargs)
>
> File "\local\Python\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals.py",
>   line 3189, in astype
>
> return self.apply('astype', dtype=dtype, **kwargs)
>
> File "\local\Python\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals.py",
>   line 3056, in apply
>       applied = getattr(b, f)(**kwargs)
>
> File "\local\Python\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals.py",
>   line 461, in astype
>       values=values, **kwargs)
>
> File "\local\Python\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals.py",
>   line 504, in _astype
>       values = _astype_nansafe(values.ravel(), dtype, copy=True)
>
> File "\local\Python\lib\site-packages\pandas\types\cast.py", line
>   531, in _astype_nansafe
>       raise ValueError('Cannot convert NA to integer') ValueError: Cannot convert NA to integer

and I want to know which row is doing the problem, but I can't find out anywhere how on exception to print it (the row) to log, like it the input dataframe is:

> ```
> name
> ```
>
> 0  1.0
>
> 1  NaN
>
> 2  3.0
>
> 3  4.0

I want it to print on the row it fails on, in this case "1  NaN",
is it even possible?

Thanks,

Answer (score 6):

You can use inbuilt python library, [traceback](https://docs.python.org/3/library/traceback.html)

```
import traceback
try:
    results['name'] = results['name'].astype(float).astype(int)
except Exception as e:  # catch *all* exceptions
    tb = traceback.format_exc()
    print(tb)
    exit("Failed to convert name" + str(e), 8)

def exit(exitCode, errorMsg=None, monitor_thread=None):
   if exitCode is not None:
       logger.error(errorMsg)
       logger.error(traceback.format_exc())
   sys.exit(exitCode)
```

**UPDATE**
Simple example to check how *traceback* works :

```
import traceback

try:
    a = [] + None
except Exception as e:
    tb = traceback.format_exc()
    print(tb)
    exit("Failed to convert name" + str(e))


def exit(exitCode):
    print(exitCode)
    print(traceback.format_exc())
```

Comment: Hi, first of, thank you for your help! I edited my Q, please check it.
I already previously used format_exc() in the exit func, if I'll use it the way you did it should I expect the results I what? thanks

Comment: When you are using the `traceback.format_exc()` as per your format then you can see the error is not propagated. I have updated the answer. Check the difference

Comment: You are absolutely current, in my code the exit definition comes *before* the try catch, that's why it worked for me..

Answer (score 4):

[@argo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51916311/9209546) suggests how you can adapt your current code.

With Pandas, however, you can simply list values which are non-converted. The trick is to use `pd.to_numeric`, which has additional options, rather than `pd.Series.astype`.

For example:

```
s = pd.to_numeric(results['name'], errors='coerce').astype(int)
failed = results['name'].loc[s.isnull()]
```